# Como acionar uma função quando clicar em um input do tipo radio?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho 2 inputs do tipo `radio`. Neles, estou tentando acionar meu método JS. Porém, ao clicar no *radio button*, nada é feito. Nem se quer chega na função JS:

```
function onView1(){
    alert("oi");
    var x = document.getElementsByName("user_1");
    if(x.value== 1){
        location.href = "option_user.html";
    }else {
        alert("nao deu");
    }
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div align="center">    
            <br><br>
            <img src="images/Untitled-1.jpg"><br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="user_1" value="1" id="1" onkeyup="onView1()"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: São 2 radio, eu que não postei o restante do código. O que quero fazer, é ao clicar no radio, redirecionar para uma página especifica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer que algo aconteça quando clicar no *input*, use o evento [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) no lugar de `onkeyup`:

```js
function mudaDePagina(){
  location.href = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com';
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' onclick='mudaDePagina()'>
```